# How to extend my ultrabook iSSD volume

Tags: windows-8, ultrabook

I've just made a clean install of Windows 8 on a new Samsung Ultrabook and it has an iSSD disk with 16GB and a 500GB HDD. I Installed Windows on the iSSD disk. On the Windows setup, it shows up as 2 separated disks.

I would like to know if I can extend the C drive so that I can use the performance of the iSSD disk + the space of the HDD.

If not, what would you suggest me to do with the iSSD?

Comment: It sounds like the [Storage Spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8#Storage_Spaces) feature of Windows 8 might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to expand C drive to include iSSD and part of HDD. What you can do is to use the HDD as another partition to install programs. This way you will have best performance while using only windows, since it will only use the iSSD, but when you run another application, you will get the standard HDD performance, since it will need to read from it.
I haven't tried it myself, since my laptop has not arrived yet, but I'm going to do it, using this guide: http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/672616-guide-ux32vd-how-install-windows-7-integrated-32gb-ssd.html

It is for asus zenbook, but the concept is the same, a fresh windows install on the iSSD, using HDD as the storage partition.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post :

[Maximizing the lifetime of your SSD](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/)

It answers all your SSD related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do this, this iSSD disk is to be used for ExpressCache and not for OS install.